# Problem with Gamma Package

Tags: packages, output, display

I wanted to install the [Gamma package](http://fy.chalmers.se/~ulfgran/gamma.htm). The package seems to have installed correctly. However, I am not seeing any symbolic output. The outputs should be like [these](http://xxx.lanl.gov/pdf/hep-th/0105086v2). 
But I am getting these. Any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: I contacted with the author. He has provided me the version compatible with mathematica 11.2. I am using the same version.

Comment: The GAMMA package is still maintained to be compatible with the latest version of Mathematica. As I still use GAMMA in my research it will continue to be updated in the foreseeable future. :) Feel free to contact me if run into any problems regarding GAMMA. Ulf Gran, creator of GAMMA.

Comment: @UlfGran Welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange and thanks for the note. Could you please address the specific concerns of "Shov432" in the answer?

Comment: I deleted my original comment saying that the package is very old, since it was clearly wrong even by looking at the screenshot (which has a timestamp from 2017).

Comment: @Szabolcs I contacted dr. Gran and he helped me to resolve the issue. The issue was with particular installation of Mathematica on my machine-not with Gamma.